# Rotating Hokuyo on the Atlas?

Tags: ros, hardware, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This isn't quite ROS-related, but I figure someone around here would know - from watching the DARPA challenge and the Atlas robot, I am very curious to know what the teams use to rotate the Hokuyo lidar 360 degrees. Anyone know what the mechanism/hardware is? How are they powering/getting the data from a unit that is rotating 360deg?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112376/rotating-hokuyo-on-the-atlas?/) by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 435 on 2013-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The hardware is the Carnegie Robotics MultisenseSL sensor head, which has the Hokuyo spinning on a slip ring, allowing for continuous rotation. See also https://support.carnegierobotics.com/forums/22096703-MultiSense-SL-Product-Information for some info.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2013-12-23**:
Awesome, thanks!